# Functional style for this Scala code

Tags: scala, coding-style

A friend of mine is learning Scala and wrote this simple code to keep track of the longest line in a file:

```
val longest = (filename:String) => {
  val is = new FileInputStream(filename)
  val buf = new Array[Byte](1024)
  var longest=0 //keep track of the longest line
  var lastPos=0
  var read=0
  try {
    read = is.read(buf)
    while (read > 0) {
      for (i<-0 until read) {
        if (buf(i) == '\n') {
          val size=i-lastPos-1
          lastPos=i
          if (size>longest) {
            longest=size
          }
        }
      }
      lastPos-=buf.length
      read=is.read(buf)
    }
  } finally {
    is.close()
  }
  longest
}
```

I'm new to Scala too, but I'm pretty sure there's a lot of room for flatMaps and other functions in this code.

Could someone post a functional version of this?

Answer (score 24):

An alternative implementation:

```
def longest(filename: String) =
  Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.map(_.size).max
```

Brief explanation:

- `getLines` returns an iterator of the lines in the file;
- `map(_.size)`, equivalent to `map(line => line.size)`, returns a new iterator of the line lengths
- `max` returns the greatest line length.

Comment: How efficient is this code. I may "guess" it iterates the file ( or keeps it in memory ) three times, 1 for getLines, 1 for map , and last one to get the max, while the original code does only one pass, but I may be wrong of course.

Comment: The file will only be iterated once. When you call `map`, it does not pull any values from the iterator; it stores the `_.size` function and creates a new iterator which will apply that function to each output of the first iterator *when called*. Calling `max` finally forces the iteration.

Comment: Got it, that's why it is called `BufferedSource` :)  What about `.max`?

Comment: I meant to say `max` at the end of that comment, edited it now.

Comment: So.. that makes it 1 iteration total?  :-/

Answer (score 13):

```
val longest = (filename: String) =>
  io.Source.fromFile(filename).getLines.maxBy(_.length).length
```

Comment: Admittedly your solution with `maxBy` is more pleasant than mine, +1.

Comment: Hello @missingfaktor this looks more efficient isn't? I understand while it read the lines it applies the `_.length` code but I don't get why does it returns "length" instead of max , shouldn't that be `...minBy(_.length)[0]` or something like that?

Comment: @Oscar: Ben's code should be just as fast (given that `getLines` returns an iterator).

Comment: @Oscar: `getLines` gives you an `Iterator[String]`. `maxBy` returns the line for which the function `_.length` returns maximum value i.e. the longest line. At last, we take the `length` of the longest line.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this code is painfully imperative. In Scala the rough equivalent would be (!):

```
def longest(fileName: String) = 
  Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines().max(Ordering.fromLessThan[String](_.size < _.size)).size
```

Guess it wouldn't hurt to provide some explanation:

```
def longest(fileName: String) = Source.
    fromFile(fileName).     //file contents abstraction
    getLines().     //iterator over lines
    max(        //find the max element in iterated elements
        Ordering.fromLessThan[String](_.size < _.size)  //however, use custom comparator by line size
    ).size  //max() will return the line, we want the line length
```

Of course [*TMTOWTDI*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it) in Scala.